# unable to log in prestashop after moving: what can be the reasons?

Tags: authentication, admin, prestashop

I've got a quite recent prestashop installation, and I moved from a server to another. After moving the frontend is ok, but is impossible to access to the backoffice..

No errors, just redirects (stay) to the login page.
I tried various thigs, from re-installing, re-uploading files, re-loading the db, clear the smarty cache and so on... Nothing.

What can be the reasons of such a problem? Anyone had something similar before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue.

I've got several local git branches. They keep track of files changes, but obviously not the database changes. So yes, I can use a branch that deals with older files/prestashop versions, but the db is always the latest. Now, the remote (issued) site is still on prestashop 1.6.0.6 (for now I need it to stay 1.6.0.6), while the current active local branch is latest 1.6.0.9.

That was the problem. Solved just loading a previous local db backup of v1.6.0.6.

Hope it helps, bye!

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of the cases the problem are the cookies. Also the name of the BackOffice folder may contain some special characters. Try deleting the cookies & to rename the backoffice folder to something simple, like admin123

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your browser cache and your cookies.
2. Check `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` in `ps_configuration` table.
3. Manually clear smarty cache: remove all files from `tools/smarty/compile` and `tools/smarty/cache`.